# How do i store order in my database after payment is successful in django

Tags: python, html, django, backend, e-commerce

i'm a beginner, i am working on the e-commerce app. i want to do something that if the user payment is successful, an order would be created and stored in the database.

i finally have found a way of integrating the payment gateway and when the transaction is successful, it redirect to a success page.

the problem i have here is how to create the order when the payment is successful

here is my code

```
<script>
    const API_publicKey = "<ADD YOUR PUBLIC KEY HERE>";

    function payWithRave() {
        var x = getpaidSetup({
            PBFPubKey: API_publicKey,
            customer_email: '{{address.email}}',
            amount: '{{cart.get_total_price}}',
            customer_phone: "234099940409",
            currency: "NGN",
            txref: "rave-123456",
            meta: [{
                metaname: "flightID",
                metavalue: "AP1234"
            }],
            onclose: function() {},
            callback: function(response) {
                var txref = response.data.txRef; // collect txRef returned and pass to a                    server page to complete status check.
                console.log("This is the response returned after a charge", response);
                if (
                    response.data.chargeResponseCode == "00" ||
                    response.data.chargeResponseCode == "0"
                ) {
                    "{% url 'checkout:payment_complete' %}" // redirect to a success page
                } else {
                    // redirect to a failure page.
                }

                x.close(); // use this to close the modal immediately after payment.
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

how do i go about it? what value to pass to the view?

Answer (score 0):

the way i do is, after the successful payment on payment gateway, I pass the pay reference id with amount and other relevant props to view and store them.
in your case, pass the payment order id or(any other things) in your checkout:payment_complete URL.
and in your payment_complete view, retrieve your payment order by its reference id and store its properties (anything u need) into your model.

Hope this helps you to built it.